# Amazon stolen package - who is financially responsible

Tags: united-states, refund

Who is financially responsible when an Amazon package worth of the good amount of $$$ is stolen from the front door? Would Amazon easily full refund the purchase?

Comment: I have had multiple occurrences over the last few years of Amazon's package tracking showing as 'delivered' but when I look for the item it's nowhere to be found. On every occasion, Amazon has re-delivered or refunded the order. Just call them.

Comment: Technically, you. But Amazon wants happy customers and happy sellers so as long as you haven't made a habit of having packages stolen then making you happy is a whole lot cheaper than losing you as a customer. There's a "cost of doing business" and apparently the cost and nuisance of requiring a signature for every single delivery is larger than the cost of an occasionally stolen package.

Comment: One difference may be whether you purchased directly from Amazon or whether it was from a third party seller.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but if you are concerned about such theft Amazon now provides secure lockers that you can pick up (some) orders, and the number of locations is (imo) pretty impressive.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that is 100% wrong. "you" are not responsible for the package until it was delivered to you. If they want to save money by not delivering it to you and getting your signature then they have not delivered the package. Therefore it never arrived.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify a jurisdiction. According to Amazon.ca (Canada)'s [conditions of use](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=918816&ref_=footer_cou):

> Risk of loss and title for items purchased from Amazon.ca pass to you
>   upon our delivery to the carrier or, if such items must cross an
>   international border, then risk of loss and title pass to you when
>   they clear customs.

Unambiguously, then, Amazon has no responsibility in such an event. In the specific case you list, the package was stolen from the front door. It's unlikely any carrier would claim responsibility in such a case. Your credit card may offer insurance which covers theft such as this. This is often offered as part of extended warranty or theft/loss protection.

Just because Amazon has no responsibility, they *may* still reimburse you. This would be done out of kindness, not out of legal responsibility. I have had packages go missing; I have video evidence they were not delivered, but did not need to provide (or even claim) this, for Amazon to offer a free replacement.

Comment: Amazon may say that, but the credit card rules may override that disclaimer.  Also the shipper could be responsible if they failed to add the extra shipping options the buyer requested (such as signature-on-delivery or insurance)

Comment: I think the carier has a responsibility to deliver the package. They can't just say "not our fault" if Amazon gave them the package, and it never made it to you, then they would seem to be responsible.

Comment: @DJClayworth If leaving the package at the front door is the standard practice for the service the shipper paid for, the carrier successfully delivered the package. It is not their responsibility if the package is stolen after it was delivered. Most carriers also offer services where the package is only delivered when there is someone to receive it, but such services tend to be more expensive.

Comment: I think a lawyer might well argue that "leaving the package where someone might find it" doesn't constitute "delivery".

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't know about Canada, but the choice is up to the shipper in the US. If the shipper instructs the carrier to leave the package at the door unattended, what happens afterwards is a matter between the shipper and the recipient.

Comment: And just to note, in an increasing number of cases, the shipper is more closely associated with Amazon - I believe they are technically independent contractors, but they basically are working "for" Amazon.

Comment: Yes, Amazon's own in-house delivery is really going ballistic. Just in the last year it's gone from being UPS and USPS to mostly Amazon people.